# How do I add a button to a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm new to working on the extension and want to try something, but the problem I'm having is adding a simple button in the **index.html** but it doesn't appear.

My code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DEMO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="background" onload="main()">

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#background {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

script.js

```
let button = document.createElement('button');

function main() {
    button.textContent = 'Click';
    button.onclick = () => {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Demo",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Demo extension.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```